# Gnuplot, pie chart, placing labels on left, can't see them all

Tags: charts, gnuplot

I need to make some pie charts using Gnuplot. I used the code I found here, on SO. My data file looks like this:

```
Województwo Suma
Dolnośląskie    3.6 
Kujawsko-Pomorskie  7.5
Lubelskie   4.7
Lubuskie    3.3
Łódzkie 8.1
Małopolskie 6.9 
Mazowieckie 12.5
Opolskie    2.6
Podkarpackie    6    
Podlaskie   3.4
Pomorskie   8
Śląskie 14
```

And my Gnuplot script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set encoding utf8 
set datafile separator "\t"
set termoption enhanced

set terminal epscairo enhanced color dashed rounded size 8.5, 5.5
set output '2008-2015procent_pie.eps'

stats '2008-2015procent_pie.csv' u 2 noout      # get STATS_sum (sum of column 2)

ang(x)=x*360.0/STATS_sum        # get angle (grades)
perc(x)=x*100.0/STATS_sum       # get percentage

set size square                 # square canvas
set xrange [-1:1.5]
set yrange [-1.25:1.25]
set style fill solid 1

unset border            # remove axis
unset tics                # remove tics on axis
unset colorbox            # remove palette colorbox 
unset key                 # remove titles

Ai = 0.0; Bi = 0.0;             # init angle
mid = 0.0;                      # mid angle
i = 0; j = 0;                   # color
yi  = 0.0; yi2 = 0.0;           # label position

set palette defined (1 1 0.788 0.055, 2 0.090 0.161 0.659) 

plot for [i=1:STATS_records] '2008-2015procent_pie.csv' u (0):(0):(1):(Ai):(Ai=Ai+ang($2)):(i) every ::i::i with circle linecolor palette,\
     '2008-2015procent_pie.csv' u (mid=(Ai+ang($2)), Ai=2*mid-Ai, mid=mid*pi/360.0, -0.5*cos(mid)):(-0.5*sin(mid)):(sprintf('%.1f\%', $2, perc($2))) ever\
y ::1 w labels center font ',10',\
     for [i=1:STATS_records] '2008-2015procent_pie.csv' u (1.45):(i*0.25):1 every ::i::i with labels left,\
     for [i=1:STATS_records] '+' u (1.3):(i*0.25):(i) pt 5 ps 4 lc palette
```

I have 2 problems with this script:

1. I don't see all labels, is it possible to move the labels somehow that I could see them all?
2. Colours: here, on my pie chart I have basically only 2 colours - yellow and blue. How to make it so I could have a variety of colours, different colour for different value?

My chart looks like this now:

[image]

Thank you.

**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------EDIT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I changed a bit my script, as suggested by @RolandSmith, also, I modified a little my data file, Now it looks like this:

```
Województwo Suma
Dolnośląskie    3.6 
Kujawsko-Pomorskie  7.5
Lubelskie   4.7
Lubuskie    3.3
Łódzkie 8.1
Małopolskie 6.9 
Mazowieckie 12.5
Opolskie    2.6
Podkarpackie    6    
Podlaskie   3.4
Pomorskie   8
Śląskie 14
Świętokrzyskie  2.8  
Warmińsko-Mazurskie 4    
Wielkopolskie   7.9
Zachodniopomorskie  4.6
```

And the modified script:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot

set encoding utf8 
set datafile separator "\t"
set termoption enhanced

set terminal epscairo enhanced color dashed rounded size 8.5, 5.5
set output '2008-2015procent_pie.eps'

stats '2008-2015procent_pie.csv' u 2 noout      # get STATS_sum (sum of column 2)

ang(x)=x*360.0/STATS_sum        # get angle (grades)
perc(x)=x*100.0/STATS_sum       # get percentage

set size square                 # square canvas
set xrange [-1:1.5]
set yrange [-1.25:1.25]
set style fill solid 1

unset border            # remove axis
unset tics                # remove tics on axis
unset colorbox            # remove palette colorbox 
unset key                 # remove titles

Ai = 0.0; Bi = 0.0;             # init angle
mid = 0.0;                      # mid angle
i = 0; j = 0;                   # color
yi  = 0.0; yi2 = 0.0;           # label position

set palette rgb 33,13,10;

plot for [i=1:STATS_records] '2008-2015procent_pie.csv' u (0):(0):(1):(Ai):(Ai=Ai+ang($2)):(i) every ::i::i with circle linecolor palette,\
     '2008-2015procent_pie.csv' u (mid=(Ai+ang($2)), Ai=2*mid-Ai, mid=mid*pi/360.0, -0.5*cos(mid)):(-0.5*sin(mid)):(sprintf('%.1f\%', $2, perc($2))) every ::1 w labels center font ',10',\
     for [i=1:STATS_records] '2008-2015procent_pie.csv' u (1.45):(i*0.25)-1.9:1 every ::i::i with labels left,\
     for [i=1:STATS_records] '+' u (1.3):(i*0.25)-1.9:(i) pt 5 ps 4 lc palette
```

Now the problem is with labels - I still can't see all of them. There should be 16 labels, as you can see from the CSV file. I tried to change the page size, with no success. Thank you for help.

Current pie:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. To move the labels in the pie-chart inwards or outwards, change the "-0.5" in front of the `sin` and `cos`. To move the labels and the color-squares, change `(i*0.25)` to `(i*0.25)-1.2` in the third and fourth plot.

   **Update:** Change `(i*0.25)` to e.g. `(i*0.18)` to make the distance between the labels smaller. And change `ps 4` to e.g. `ps 3` to make the squares smaller.
2. Define a larger palete. Your current one only has *two* entries. Get one with as least as much colors as you have entries. You could use [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) to generate palette colors.

Some other points.

- While this is really very clever, you're probably pushing gnuplot *way* beyond what it was intended. Consider using another tool like e.g. [Python's `matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_demo_features.html).
- Your data doesn't add up to 100, but only to 80.6. So you should scale your figure properly using the `ang` and `perc` functions. I can't put my finger on it, but it doesn't look right.
- In the `sprintf`, you should only use the percentage:`sprintf('%.1f\%', perc($2))`

Comment: Thank you, you helped me again :) However, I have some further issues, my main problem is that I still can't see all the labels. Could you be so kind and please see my edit?